# Runtime created TButton control on High DPI aware application doesn't scale to monitor's DPI

Tags: delphi

I am using High DPI option in Delphi 10 Seattle project.  The controls (buttons, labels, check box) on forms scale well on different DPI setting.  These controls were drop to form at design time.

However, I have some `TButton` control that I created at runtime.  These runtime created button doesn't scale and honour the monitor's DPI setting.  For example, a design time `TButton` with height of `25` at design time scale to `31`.  But the runtime created `TButton` control doesn't scale from `25` to `31`.

I may do extra calculate on the left, top, width and height on runtime created `TButton` control but that would be tedious.  Is there any ready solution available in `Delphi` that allow us to scale according to monitor's DPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform this scaling in your code. The VCL does not attempt to perform any such scaling for controls created manually at runtime.

You can use the protected `ChangeScale` method of `TControl` to perform the scaling. This accepts two parameters, `M` and `D`, the numerator and denominator respectively. Pass `Form.PixelsPerInch` for `M` and `96` for `D`.

Comment: There are more side effects for this issue.  I have reported to [RSP-37124](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37124)